# Exception: Unable to generate build files for windows build

Tags: flutter, windows, flutter-dependencies

While trying to run the default flutter app am getting error after i have downloaded the firebase plugins - firebase_core, firebase_auth, firebase_anayltics and cloud_firestore
[here is the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCzWm.png)

So I trun command `flutter -v run -d windows` and it is still the same, Please let me know what is this issue about Thanks